# How to invoke JSF validator on keyup event?

Tags: validation, jsf

I have implemented a JSF validator based on [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532994/how-to-implement-jsf-validator).

How can I trigger it on keyup event of `<h:inputText>`?

I am using JSF 2.0 and Richfaces 4.1.0 Final.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attach ajax listeners to DOM events on any JSF HTML input component by [`<f:ajax>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html) tag.

```
<h:inputText id="foo" value="#{bean.foo}">
    <f:ajax event="keyup" execute="@this" render="fooMessage" />
    <f:validator validatorId="fooValidator" />
</h:inputText>
<h:message id="fooMessage" for="foo" />
```

The `fooValidator` can be just a simple [`Validator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/validator/Validator.html) implementation which you register in the faces context by [`@FacesValidator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/validator/FacesValidator.html) annotation.

```
@FacesValidator("fooValidator")
public class FooValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        // ...

        if (invalid) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Fail!"));
        }
    }

}
```

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2 - Ajax validation](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxValidation)

In RichFaces it's not much different. There's only the `<a4j:ajax>` tag which is basically just `<f:ajax>` on steroids. But it does not really provide additional benefits in *this particular* case. See also [Is there any difference between f:ajax and a4j:ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590361/is-there-any-difference-between-fajax-and-a4jajax)

Comment: Thanks for the help, let me check and will update you, just a small follow up question, Can I add 2 Validator, 1 on keyup event and other one on Form Submit, if yes, then how?