# JSF Validate on keyup event

Tags: validation, jsf-2

i want to implement a validation for a username. The 'normal' way to do it
is something like that:

```
<h:outputText for="username" value="Username:" />
<p:inputText id="username" value="#{registerService.username}" >
    <f:validator binding="#{usernameValidator}" />
</p:inputText>
<p:message for="username" />

<p:commandButton type="submit" value="Submit" action="#{registerService.addUser}" ajax="false" update="panel" validateClient="true" />
```

But what i now want to do is to validate the username everytime
the user presses a key in the username inputText without pressing
the commandButton.

So each character should trigger the validation and should update
the messages field for username to show the user instantly if the 
username is already present in database or not.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Found:

[Ajax Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904658/how-to-invoke-jsf-validator-on-keyup-event)

This triggers the validation!

```
<h:inputText id="foo" value="#{bean.foo}">
    <f:ajax event="keyup" execute="@this" render="fooMessage" />
    <f:validator validatorId="fooValidator" />
</h:inputText>
<h:message id="fooMessage" for="foo" />
```